# C++ - Read log level in performance oriented way

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, logging

The logger component is a static library. Application (service) loads around 20 DLLs. Application and DLLs are linked with the static logger library. There are other applications (UI/CLI) that update the log level in the shared memory on Windows.

Main application and DLLs read log level from the shared memory and decide whether to log or not a particular log statement. Reading log level is protected by the named mutex which has a huge performance penalty.

What can be the best way to make the reading log level lightweight.

Comment: Make log level atomic so that it can be read without locking the mutex? Too little information to answer definitively...

Comment: Yeah, more details required but, first thought is: can you not keep a local copy of the log level and just update them only when it changes?

Comment: ..add a 'setLogLevel()' to every DLL interface, bind up in your usual way, early or late, and call them all from your CLI/GUI when there is a change?  The mutex seems an overkill anyway, as commented by @rustyx.

Comment: I thought of keeping a local copy but it requires monitoring thread in all the DLL's which waits for log level change event when log level is changed from UI/CLI. Having 20 threads to read the log level is not a good idea. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Can you not just call in to a setter function in the DLLs?

Answer (score 0):

Like @rustyx suggests, using an [`std::atomic<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) is likely your best choice. The cache coherence protocol will take care of synchronization for you and it will be as fast as possible without having to monitor changes yourself.

A few points:

- Make it as small as possible, for instance use `atomic_uchar`.
- Verify the implementation is lock-free via the `is_lock_free()` method.
- Verify it is address-free, since you need keep it in shared memory (check the documentation of your compiler or standard library for this).

Otherwise, if 1. the atomic overhead is too big for you, 2. the log level almost never changes and 3. you do not mind a small "delay" after the change, then you could create a local copy and have a queue of events that you monitor for changes every once in a "while".

Comment: AFAIK, atomic will work within the process. I need to read log level from the shared memory.

Comment: Why should the change be as small as possible? Cache coherence works based on cachelines which on x86 is 64 bytes.

Comment: @pveentjer To increase the chance that the implementation is lock-free. Some architectures may not have a 64-byte atomic type but they may have a 32-bit one.

Comment: @PeeyushJain It will work in practical implementations, but it is not guaranteed by the standard.